# why developers use c/c++ for embedded systems rather than high level language like python compared to c?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, embedded, system

can we access memory via python like we do in c/c++?
Have been programming in c for a while and came across this question?
I see that over 90 percent of the code is written in c/c++ for embedded systems

Comment: Programming languages are just tools.  Some are more suitable for some kinds of programs.  Python's big strength is readability and easily making changes to the programs, but at a tradeoff for performance compared to C or C++.  C and C++, in contrast, are about as performant as you can get; but at the cost of taking considerably more development time (especially for very large projects).

Comment: I would argue that `C++` is just as higher level language as python. However this is likely to do with resources. Embedded devices usually have little memory and lower powered CPUs so using `C++/C` maximizes the use of both. Python has a lot of overhead and makes less efficient use of the CPU.

Comment: Often you can't use memory on an embedded system the way Python does. A classical embedded system has a limited no memory management unit that cannot deal well with the frequent allocation and deallocation of dynamic resources Python expects. The available memory will fragment or force a lot non-deterministic time to be spent working around the fragmentation. On the other hand, if your embedded system is something beefy like a Linux-running Raspberry Pi, go nuts with Python.

Comment: Its sort of a good question, because when you think about it most/all of python is simply made with pieces made in the 'c/c++' language. The issue is primarily limited "OS capabilities" and/or limited resources (ie. cpu/memory since python is actually very slow compared to c++ for most heavy duty tasks - this is why you in python use eg. packages like the well known 'nympy' as that moves the heavy resource using code from python into c/c++, where as those computations could have been very slow if programmed directly in python just to give an example).

Comment: It's as simple as this: because C comes with the actual possibility to do hardware-related programming. Python does not - it relies on a C back end. In order to do hardware-related programming, you need "pointers" or similar representation of addresses. You need type punning, you need volatile, you need inline asm and so on. Even C++ is quite unsuitable. I think some 80-90% of all firmware nowadays is written in C, followed by asm (still), followed by other languages like C++ or Ada.

Comment: The storage requirements of the compiler and bytecode compiler will not fit into 256 bytes of RAM.

Comment: Try writing an embedded system in Python, and you will find out

Comment: @user253751 people do try though and for most hobbyist use, it's perfectly fine. OP look at [microphython](https://micropython.org/) and [espruino](https://www.espruino.com/). They don't give you fine tuned access to your hardware but allow you though to create quickly without much though but there is exactly wherein C and C++ excel, fine tuned thoughtfully put together programs.

Answer (score 8):

Languages like Python are run through interpretation, which means that you would need another software in between your hardware and your program to read it.

On the other hand, languages like C or C++ are compiled into machine codes, so that the machine can read them directly.

And since you asked about memory management, Python does not give you precise memory management, where as C or C++ does.

Answer (score 6):

> why developers use c/c++ for embedded systems rather than high level language like python compared to c?

The answer to this is most certainly partially historical.

[C was originally designed to be used for operating systems](https://www.javatpoint.com/history-of-c-language#:%7E:text=C%20programming%20language%20was%20developed,as%20B%2C%20BCPL%2C%20etc.):

> Initially, C language was developed to be used in UNIX operating system. It inherits many features of previous languages such as B and BCPL.

I would imagine this had a lot to do with its use in embedded systems.

C++, on the other hand, [was derived from C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B):

> In 1979, Bjarne Stroustrup, a Danish computer scientist, began work on "C with Classes", the predecessor to C++.[15] The motivation for creating a new language originated from Stroustrup's experience in programming for his PhD thesis. Stroustrup found that Simula had features that were very helpful for large software development, but the language was too slow for practical use, while BCPL was fast but too low-level to be suitable for large software development. When Stroustrup started working in AT&T Bell Labs, he had the problem of analyzing the UNIX kernel with respect to distributed computing. Remembering his Ph.D. experience, Stroustrup set out to enhance the C language with Simula-like features.[16] C was chosen because it was general-purpose, fast, portable and widely used. As well as C and Simula's influences, other languages also influenced this new language, including ALGOL 68, Ada, CLU and ML.
>
> Initially, Stroustrup's "C with Classes" added features to the C compiler, Cpre, including classes, derived classes, strong typing, inlining and default arguments.[17]
>
> In 1982, Stroustrup started to develop a successor to C with Classes, which he named "C++" (++ being the increment operator in C) after going through several other names. New features were added, including virtual functions, function name and operator overloading, references, constants, type-safe free-store memory allocation (new/delete), improved type checking, and BCPL style single-line comments with two forward slashes (//). Furthermore, Stroustrup developed a new, standalone compiler for C++, Cfront.

Consequently, while the languages have now significantly diverged, they were very similar to each other.

[Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python), on the other hand, was designed to be used **with** operating systems, not to create them:

> The programming language Python was conceived in the late 1980s,[1](https://www.javatpoint.com/history-of-c-language#:%7E:text=C%20programming%20language%20was%20developed,as%20B%2C%20BCPL%2C%20etc.) and its implementation was started in December 1989[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) by Guido van Rossum at CWI in the Netherlands as a successor to ABC capable of exception handling and interfacing with the Amoeba operating system.

Comment: The OS part isn't very relevant for embedded. More so the fact that C (and BCPL etc) aren't very high level. You can trace their heritage back to assembler. A lot of C features are designed to directly reflect the underlying bitwise operators. Like for example, why is negative right shift impl.defined in C? Because the underlying assembler supports both logical and arithmetic shift. You can trace the various oddities in C directly down to the machine code.

Comment: My point of bringing up OSes is because it demonstrates that C is meant for working with hardware.

Comment: Eh not really. The average system level programmer doesn't necessarily write code that works directly with hardware. For example in a PC you have the various internal buses where you plug on PCBs, hard drives, DVD etc. Inside those devices sits a microcontroller/SoC - the embedded system that does the actual "talking" to the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Cost.

It costs more to have a platform that can run a python program in the python VM verses one that runs natively compiled applications.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulation of memory directly is difficult via python which is very much required for embedded systems programming at certain use cases.

Also, a garbage collector is occassionally run in python that finds unused memory objects and frees them. It should be noted that it may sometime consume more time than expected on garbage collection.

A typical realtime embedded systems expects faster execution at predictable time . C,C++ provide faster execution speed and good control over memory that is required for a typical embedded system.  Hence python is mostly not considered in such cases.

Answer (score -1):

I'd argue that the embedded space *is* using Python.  [CircuitPython](https://circuitpython.org/) and [MicroPython](https://micropython.org/) are both versions of Python that are specifically designed for use on embedded systems.  Sure, C and C++ are still very popular, but Python is definitely gaining traction.

At this point in time, most every microcontroller board available from [Adafruit](https://Adafruit.com) has a port of one of those two Python systems available for it.